# windows universal app check tablet

Tags: c#, xaml, win-universal-app

I am designing some application using Universal app from visual studio, and i would like some code to execute when the program is running on phone or tablet, the phone part is not a problem since i can use '#if WINDOWS_PHONE_APP' but how can I know if the application is on a tablet?

Comment: What specifically do you care about? Is it the size of the screen, the lack of a keyboard / mouse, some legal definition of "tablet", etc?

Comment: i am looking for lack of keyboard actualy

Answer (score 1):

If you want to detect a keyboard, use the [KeyboardCapabilities object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/windows.devices.input.keyboardcapabilities.aspx). Note that starting with Windows 10, phone can also have wireless keyboards attached.